# Getting started with QGIS, but can't find sample data files on my machine

Tags: qgis

I'm just getting started with QGIS. After installation, the User Manual directs you to load raster and vector data. It says "browse to folder qgis_sample_data/raster/." Well, that folder does not exist under Program Files/QGIS Brighton. It next directs you to find and load an .img file. There are no .img files in the current installation of QGIS.
So, what's going on here? Is it just a bad user manual?

Answer (score 8):

You have to download the sample data before as mentioned in the [User Guide Sample Data](http://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/getting_started.html#sample-data) paragraph.

> The Windows installer has an option to download the QGIS sample
>   dataset. If checked, the data will be downloaded to your My Documents
>   folder and placed in a folder called GIS Database. You may use Windows
>   Explorer to move this folder to any convenient location. If you did
>   not select the checkbox to install the sample dataset during the
>   initial QGIS installation, you may do one of the following:
>
> - Use GIS data that you already have
> - Download sample data from http://qgis.org/downloads/data/qgis_sample_data.zip
> - Uninstall QGIS and reinstall with the data download option checked (only recommended if the above solutions are unsuccessful)
>
> For GNU/Linux and Mac OS X, there are not yet dataset installation
>   packages available as rpm, deb or dmg. To use the sample dataset,
>   download the file qgis_sample_data as a ZIP archive from
>   http://download.osgeo.org/qgis/data/qgis_sample_data.zip and unzip the
>   archive on your system.

Comment: It's better to include the information or at least a summary of it rather than just link to the answer. Links can break, rendering the answer useless.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that QGis never tells you where it *puts* the sample data if you select the option to download example data during installation.

Even in QGis 3.0. And no, you won't be able to see where it went in your browser because QGis handled the download. And neither will you be able to find the newly created directory "qgis_sample_data".

This is why your best bet is to follow the suggestion of lrssvt, download the data again, unzip it and put it where you can find it.

Those who wish to learn where GQis stashed the files can do a global search for e.g. the landcover.img file.